# how can I store input data to an options of array?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

this is my react and nodejs code where I want to create polls using react form but I don't understand what goes wrong with my code...!`Here I have 4 input field with { option1: "", option2: "", option3: "", option4: "" }, but I don't know how to store data just like I store data using POSTMAN...! CAN ANYONE HELP PLEASE help....!
REACT JS CODE --->

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import { isAutheticated } from "../auth/helper/index";
import { createaPoll } from "./helper/adminapicall";

const AddPoll = () => {
  const { user, token } = isAutheticated();
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    question: "",
    options: { option1: "", option2: "", option3: "", option4: "" },
    error: "",
    loading: "false",
    getRedirect: false,
    formData: "",
  });

  const { question, options, error, loading, getRedirect, formData } = value;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // setError("");
    setValue({ ...value, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    // console.log(event.target.value);
    const newOption = {
      ...value.options,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    };
    setValue((prev) => ({ ...prev, options: newOption }));
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValue({ ...value, error: "", loading: true });
    // console.log(handel);
    const { option1, option2, option3, option4 } = options;
    const newOptions = [option1, option2, option3, option4];
    createaPoll(user._id, token, { question, options: newOptions }).then(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.error) {
          setValue({ ...value, error: data.error });
        } else {
          setValue({
            ...value,
            question: "",
            options: { option1: "", option2: "", option3: "", option4: "" },
            error: "",
            loading: "false",
            getRedirect: false,
            formData: "",
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="AddPoll">
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Add New Poll</h1>
        <form>
          <textarea
            rows="4"
            cols="50"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Question"
            name="question"
            value={question}
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            autoFocus
          ></textarea>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Option1"
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            name="option1"
            value={options.option1}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Option2"
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            name="option2"
            value={options.option2}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Option3"
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            name="option3"
            value={options.option3}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Option4"
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            name="option4"
            value={options.option4}
          />
          <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit} className="btn Submitbtn">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddPoll;
```

NODEJS CODE --->

```
exports.createPolls = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { question, options } = req.body;
    const dynamic = {};
    options.forEach((opt) => {
      dynamic[opt.toLowerCase()] = [];
    });
    const polls = await Poll.create({
      question,
      options: dynamic,
    });
    polls.save((err, polls) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: "Saving Poll in DB failed",
        });
      }
      res.json(polls);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    error.status = 400;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

And when I did with POSTMAN it's work fine! Here is my POSTMAN IMAGE
[image]

Whenever I click to submit button using react form got an error on react form ( Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined )at line number - 39

and when I check my node server it also shows me an error ( Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined )
I don't understand why this is happening ...! because POSTMAn works fine with this code but react form not,,,! please help...!

Comment: what does data.error console.log() as?

Comment: what does data.error console.log() as? --- undefined

Answer (score 0):

options need to be an array to be possible to use the forEach method to iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

Error responses need to be put after the then() block in a catch() block. And you can target the err response data with err.response.data.error to get your message. This way any response.status !== 200 can have its own statements.

```js
 const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValue({ ...value, error: "", loading: true });
    // console.log(handel);
    const { option1, option2, option3, option4 } = options;
    const newOptions = [option1, option2, option3, option4];
    createaPoll(user._id, token, { question, options: newOptions }).then(
      (data) => {
          setValue({
            ...value,
            question: "",
            options: { option1: "", option2: "", option3: "", option4: "" },
            error: "",
            loading: "false",
            getRedirect: false,
            formData: "",
          }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response.data.error)
          setValue({ ...value, error: err.response.data.error });
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: nodejs server error - ( Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined )

Comment: and reactjs error - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

If options are just strings, just put them in an array and pass them into your req object like this:

```js
const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValue({ ...value, error: "", loading: true });
    // console.log(handel);
    const { option1, option2, option3, option4 } = options;
    const newOptions = [option1, option2, option3, option4];
    createaPoll(user._id, token, { question, newOptions }).then( //like this
      (data) => {
          setValue({
            ...value,
            question: "",
            options: { option1: "", option2: "", option3: "", option4: "" },
            error: "",
            loading: "false",
            getRedirect: false,
            formData: "",
          }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response.data.error)
          setValue({ ...value, error: err.response.data.error });
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

Then console.log your newOptions array and req.body in your route to see if your data is being directed properly,

```js
exports.createPolls = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { question, options } = req.body;
    console.log(question, options, req.body) // what does this look like?
    const dynamic = {};
    options.forEach((opt) => {
      dynamic[opt.toLowerCase()] = [];
    });
    const polls = await Poll.create({
      question,
      options: dynamic,
    });
    polls.save((err, polls) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: "Saving Poll in DB failed",
        });
      }
      res.json(polls);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    error.status = 400;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Maybe the data isnt being passed to the route propery?

Comment: console.log(question, options, req.body) ---> undefined undefined {}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: How does the data save to your db when the route doesn't even have the data? Check the react chrome dev tools extension to make sure your front end choices are setting.